# Get a user's photo in the size of the profile photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, photo

I'm developing website Facebook application using C#. I can get the information using:

```
FacebookClient FBApp = new FacebookClient(getAccessToken);
dynamic user = FBApp.Get("/me");
```

and I can get a user's friends by:

```
dynamic friends = FBApp.Get("/me/friends");
```

All this does not contain any links to the photo. I can get the user photo using the link https://graph.facebook.com/*[user_id]*/picture.

But this shows a very small photo... How can I get the photo in a size similar to the size of the profile photo?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To get a user profile picture of a specific size, call

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture?type=SIZE
```

where SIZE should be replaced with one of the words

```
square
small
normal
large
```

depending on the size you want.

This call will return a [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) to a single image with its size based on your chosen type parameter.

For example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture?type=large
```

returns a URL to a large version of the image.

Comment: if you use https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture&type=SIZE Then it will return an error message :-  {
   "error": {
      "message": "Unknown path components: /picture&type=large",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
} .  You have to use https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture?type=SIZE

Answer (score 0):

Try FQL:

`SELECT pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())`

...where `pic_square` can be one of `pic_small`, `pic_big`, `pic_square`, `pic`

That'll give you URLs for the corresponding user's friends' profile picture at the given size.

e.g.:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20pic_square%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20IN%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20%3D%20me%28%29%29

Answer (score 0):

@Gunnar Karlsson is true, but the sizes (in pixels) of pictures are not the same. For example, 180x180;180x135. The aspect depends on the original uploaded picture

Answer (score 0):

To get a facebook user profile picture of a specific size, call

```
graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture?width=900
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get picture by this way: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/search?fields=id,picture&q={your query}&type=user&access_token=AccessToken