# facebook application needs dimensions of profile picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the server flow facebook application and when I get the user's profile picture, I save that URL in my HttpSession.  However, I also have a javascript feature that when mousing over certain posts in my application, and my user is a facebook user, I show the picture at about 100 pixels size.  However, I don't know the relative height/width ratio of the picture, and it is framed in a box.  I need to know the height and width of the facebook picture that was uploaded by the user, but I can't find this information in the facebook developer graph api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Profile picture dimensions depend on which type you select. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299528/get-users-photo-in-the-size-of-the-profile-photo/10301103#10301103) answer for a summary of types. Each type corresponds to a maximum size.

The API only specifies the maximum size for profile images, not the actual size.

Square

```
maximum width and height of 50px.
```

Small

```
maximum width of 50px and a maximum height of 150px.
```

Normal

```
maximum width of 100px and a maximum height of 300px.
```

Large

```
maximum width of 200px and a maximum height of 600px.
```

If you call the default USER_ID/picture you get the square type.

Comment: So if I ask for the square size, I will get guaranteed square?

Comment: Yes, if the image file exists...The User table doc states for all picture fields that:"This URL may be blank". I don't know in what scenario it wouldn't exist since if the user doesn't upload a profile pic the request returns the default blue and white silhouette. But that what the doc says. See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/. So, if you ask for a square, and you do get a picture file, it will be a square.